# Applying an R method only to *matrices* of a certain class

Tags: r, methods

A package I am developing contains an [R method](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.3.1/topics/Methods), and have a function that I wish to apply to numeric matrices only.

My function will call a C function that expects a numeric matrix as its input. I want to make it easy for authors of other packages to write separate handlers for (say) numeric vectors or character matrices without having to edit the function in my package.

For the sake of a simple example, let's say I want the function to add one to matrices:

```
AddOne <- function (x) UseMethod('AddOne')
AddOne.[numeric-AND-matrix] <- function (x) add_one_in_c(x)

AddOne(1) # Should report "No applicable method"
AddOne(matrix("one")) # Should report "No applicable method"
AddOne(matrix(1)) # Should send the matrix to add_one_in_c()
```

Just looking to see whether `x` is a numeric, or a matrix, is too general:

```
AddOne <- function (x) UseMethod('AddOne')
AddOne.numeric <- function (x) message("X is numeric, but may not be a matrix")
AddOne.matrix <- function (x) message("X is a matrix, but may not be numeric")
```

And I've been [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322898/usemethod-vs-inherits-to-determine-an-objects-class-in-r) from using `inherits` for this sort of purpose:

```
AddOne <- function (x) UseMethod('AddOne')
AddOne.matrix <- function (x) {
  if (inherits(x, 'numeric')) {
    add_one_in_c(x)
  } else {
    NextMethod(x)
  }
}
```

This last solution would also be difficult to extend. Perhaps someone else could handle character matrices by writing `AddOne.character()`, but this function would also have to handle character vectors.

Is there a way to do this that takes full advantage of the Methods protocols?

Comment: I think it is not possible to have a "clean" solution like `AddOne.[numeric-AND-matrix]` as both `matrix` and `numeric` are implicit classes based on base types: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/base-types.html and https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-dispatch. Or you would have to explicitly define the class `numericmatrix`

Answer (score 2):

You can define a default method that handles everything except matrices. Then within the matrix method, if it is anything other than numeric, you simply call `NextMethod`, which will invoke the default method. Therefore you only need to write a single error message and a single matrix method.

```
# Here's a stand in for your C function:
add_one_in_c   <- function(x) x + 1

AddOne         <- function(x) UseMethod('AddOne')
AddOne.default <- function(x) stop("No applicable method")
AddOne.matrix  <- function(x) if (is.numeric(x)) add_one_in_c(x) else NextMethod()
```

So, testing it we get:

```
char_matrix <- matrix(LETTERS[1:9], nrow = 3)
num_matrix  <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)

AddOne(num_matrix)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    5    8
#> [2,]    3    6    9
#> [3,]    4    7   10

AddOne(char_matrix)
#>  Error in AddOne.default(char_matrix) : No applicable method

AddOne(1:9)
#>  Error in AddOne.default(1:9) : No applicable method
```

---

**Addendum**

Another way to do this that makes it easier to add methods for further classes as needed is to have the function `AddOne` as a "gatekeeper" that ensures only matrices are handled, and which then dispatches an S3 method according to the class of the underlying data:

```
add_one_in_c   <- function(x) x + 1

AddOne  <- function(x) 
{
  if(class(x) != "matrix") stop("No applicable method")
  return(AddOne_basic(as.vector(x), nrow(x), ncol(x)))
}

AddOne_basic <- function(x, r, c) UseMethod("AddOne_basic")

AddOne_basic.default <- function(x, r, c) stop("No appicable method")

AddOne_basic.numeric <- function(x, r, c) {
  dim(x) <- c(r, c); 
  add_one_in_c(x)
}
```

So to expand the handling of `AddOne` to other basic types, you add the appropriate `AddOne_basic` method. Obviously when writing a package you may decide not to export the "back end" `AddOne_basic` methods.

Comment: I'm not clear how this differs materially from my final suggestion, as if `AddOne.default()` is not defined, R will throw an error already. I've edited my question to expound the potential limitations of this approach: it would not be easy for someone to add a handler for character matrices (say) without editing my code.

Comment: @ms609 I see what you mean, though it's important to point out that there are only a small number of basic types in R. I have presented an alternative above that makes it easier to expand functionality.

Comment: @ms609 sorry - forgot to commit my changes. Now updated.

Comment: Nice suggestion! Perhaps it would be neater still to go `AddOne.matrix <- function (x) AddOneMatrix(x)` with `AddOneMatrix.numeric <- function(x) UseMethod('AddOneMatrix')` and `AddOneMatrix.numeric <- function (x) add_one_in_c(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that would also be discouraged, but couldn't you just test like this:

```r
AddOne.matrix <- function (x) {
  all(methods::is(x[1], 'numeric'), methods::is(x, 'matrix')) {
    add_one_in_c(x)
  } else {
    NextMethod(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works if I have a function `AddOne.character()` that (only) handles character vectors, and a user wishes to write their own function that handles character matrices (but not vectors): their `AddOne.character()` that would override mine.